# JQL Tricks Plug In Filtering

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql

I'm working on developing a filter in JIRA using JQL that can allow me to pull from all of the projects my team is working on.

What we would like to be able to do is be able to search using `VersionMatches("")`. Using *VersionMatches* we would like to be able to search for just the **Month** and **Year** for each month. What we currently have is it set up like this

2.9.4(5/21/2013)

Is it possible to search only month and year and skip over the day portion?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find the answer to this problem by looking through Java Regex documentation

To get it to skip over the **Day** section you need to create a filter that is similar to this

**versionMatches(".*6/\d{2}/2013\)")**

the \d{2} will skip over the day section and only search for the **Month** and **Year**